# Load page with QWebPage

Tags: c++, qt5.3

I want QWebPage for load html page (because I am in console application and I can't use QWebView).

When I do this :

```
bool webview::load(Arguments *args)
{
    QRegularExpression url("^(file|http)://");
    QRegularExpression fullPath("^/");

    QRegularExpressionMatch pathMatch = fullPath.match(args->getSource());
    QRegularExpressionMatch urlMatch = url.match(args->getSource());

    frame =  navigateur->mainFrame();
    if(pathMatch.hasMatch()) {
        frame->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(args->getSource()));
    } else {
        if (urlMatch.hasMatch()) {
            frame->load(QUrl(args->getSource()));
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", qPrintable(QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Error: Invalide source file")));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have this error :

```
/home/morgan/htmltopdf/webview.cpp:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QWebFrame'
         frame->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(args->getSource()));
              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include <QWebFrame>`, the definition of `QWebFrame` is missing here.